# skip stmt block

Tags: php, insert

I am brand new to php and I ran into a problem that has already taken a few hours of poking around and researching and I could not find anything like it anywhere around the net.

Database:MyPHPAdmin winserver

Goal: Create a new row in table 'photo'. Take the last insert p_id for the current user and update the table accessible_to by creating a new row with that p_id.
I know I can create a trigger, and no it does not work either don't know why. Run out of ideas how.

What I found out by simply printing before-in-after the if statement
`if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("insert into accessible_to values(?, ?, ?)"))`
is that it just bypasses it.

Please post your suggestions.
P.S. The if statement above to which I am referring has been twisted in several ways and yet it does not work.
The connection is already imported.

Thank you a lot.

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION["id"])) {
  echo "You are not logged in. ";
  echo "You will be returned to the homepage in 3 seconds or click <a href=\"index.php\">here</a>.\n";
  header("refresh: 3; index.php");
}
else {
  //if the user have uploaded a photo, insert it into database
  if(isset($_POST["ext"])) {  
    //insert into database, note that p_id is auto_increment
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("insert into photo (ext, owner_id) values (?,?)")) {
      $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST["ext"], $_SESSION["id"]);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->close();
      $id = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["id"]);    
    } 
    //The following function is fetching the last added p_id in PHOTO by the user with the current SESSION
    //Do not simply get the last p_id in PHOTO because someone else might have just added another picture meanwhile
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select MAX(p_id) from photo where owner_id = ?")){
      $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);    
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->bind_result($p_id);
      if ($stmt->fetch()){
        $p_id = htmlspecialchars($p_id);
      } 
    }
    echo "BEFORE accessible_to insertion";
echo '<br />';

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("insert into accessible_to values(?, ?, ?)")){
    echo "Finally inside accessible_to insertion";
    echo '<br />';
    $stmt->bind_param("iss", $p_id, $id, 'T');
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
echo "AFTER accessible_to insertion";
echo '<br />';
 }   
     //if not then display the form for posting message
      else {
        echo "Something";
```

Comment: I got it.Ok thank you very much for your attention. SO, DO NOT FORGET TO close() the statement if you want to execute another query after that. In other words I just added $stmt->close() to the 4th IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can't boolean test an assignment and expect it to return a different result.  What you want to test for is if $stmt->execute successfully executed or not.

```
$stmt = $mysql->prepare("insert into foo values (?,?)"); 
$stmt->bind_param(1,$f1); 
$stmt->bind_param(2,$f2);

if ($stmt->execute()) { 
... worked 
} else {
... fubar
}
```

Comment: P.S. You should be using PDO.  The mysql and mysqli(unstable IMHO) libraries/apis are the older way of doing things.  If you're learning, then what's being used today. It isn't very different at all, and it should be around for a long while (so will mysql).

Comment: Thank you for the great insights. I would definitely look for PDO. Though, I tried what you have advised me and the problem is that the fifth IF statement is just being skipped. Like literary. How come? Here is some output by  using the above technique with each execute()                                                         The 1st insert was executed
The 1st select was executed
BEFORE accessible_to insertion
AFTER accessible_to insertion

Answer (score 0):

You have to start by calling mysqli::connect($server, $user, $pw, $db). The best way to do that is by constructing an object like:

```
$connection = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $db);
    if ($connection->errno) 
    {
        echo "Connection failed";
        echo $this->connection->error;
    } 
    else  
    {                                                                                    
        $stmt = $connection->prepare("insert into photo (ext, owner_id) values (?,?)")) {
  $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST["ext"], $_SESSION["id"]);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->close();

    }
```

Comment: Sorry I have not been clear enough. This connection has already been done in a separate file that is imported before the beginning of the code above. As I already said the problem is in the top-to-bottom fifth if statement.